# Wrong Python version in virtual environment

Tags: python, installation, virtualenv

I have Python 3.10.0 installed on my Mac. But when I create a virtual environment (using: python -m venv nameofvirtualenvironment) and check the Python version which is installed in the virtual environment it says that Python 3.8.10 is installed. But I really need Python 3.10.0.

Python version 3.10.0 is installed at /usr/local/bin/python3

Do you have ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Use `/usr/local/bin/python3 -m venv` instead. Or possibly `python3.10 -m venv`.

Comment: You could make an alias like `alias python310 = /usr/local/bin/python3.10`, and work with that. At least, normally, Python minor versions are also installed by their specific minor-version name.

Comment: @9769953 That's a syntax error in Bourne-compatible shells. You might want to `alias python=python3.10` though. (Though generally, functions and scripts are superior to aliases in multiple respects.)